# Checked Checkbox Not Working?

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an HTML form that posts to a PHP script. Everything is working except the checkbox. When it is checked, the value is not being posted.

**HTML:**

```
<input name="test" id="checkbox-02" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

**PHP:**

```
if(!isset($_POST['test'])) {
  $eventRepeat="No";
}

if(isset($_POST['test'])) {
  $eventRepeat="Yes";
}
```

When this code runs, $eventRepeat always comes out as "No." I tried using the command "print_r($_POST)" and all inputs are posted except the checkbox, **even when it is checked**.

Any ideas what could cause this? I do have jQuery running so when it is checked two divs appear. Could that somehow be interfering? Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#checkbox-02').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
    //  ^
       $('#repeatUntilDIV').fadeIn('slow');
       $('#repeatFrequencyDIV').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

For reference, here is the full code:

```
           <form class="cmxform form-horizontal tasi-form" id="commentForm" role="form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEventTitle" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Event Title</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEventTitle" name="inputEventTitle" placeholder="Event Title" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEventDescription" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Description</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEventTitle" name="inputEventDescription" placeholder="Event Description" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEventStartTime" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Start Time</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <select name="inputEventStartTime" class="form-control" id="dp1" required>
                <option label="Start Time">
                <option value="12:00AM">12:00AM</option>
                <option value="12:15AM">12:15AM</option>
                <option value="12:30AM">12:30AM</option>
                <option value="12:45AM">12:45AM</option>
                <option value="1:00AM">1:00AM</option>
              </select>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEventEndTime" class="col-lg-2 control-label">End Time</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <select name="inputEventEndTime" class="form-control" id="dp1" required>
                <option label="End Time">
                <option value="1:00AM">1:00AM</option>
                <option value="1:15AM">1:15AM</option>
                <option value="1:30AM">1:30AM</option>
                <option value="1:45AM">1:45AM</option>
                <option value="2:00AM">2:00AM</option>
              </select>                </div>
        </div>                      
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Date</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="dp1" name="inputEventDate" type="text" size="16" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEventDate" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Repeat?</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10 checkboxes">
              <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-02"> </label>
              <input name="test" id="checkbox-02" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Yes, I want to repeat this event.
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group" id="repeatUntilDIV" style="display:none;">
            <label for="inputEventEndDate" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Repeat Until</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input name="inputEventEndDate" id="eventEndDate" type="text" placeholder="End Date" class="form-control">                                            
            </div>
        </div>  
         <div class="form-group" id="repeatFrequencyDIV" style="display:none;">
            <label for="inputEventFrequency" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Repeat Every</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
             <select name="inputEventFrequency" class="form-control" id="dp1">
                <option label="Repeat Every">
                <option value="1">Repeat Every Day</option>
                <option value="2">Repeat Every Other Day</option>
                <option value="7">Repeat Every Week</option>
                <option value="14">Repeat Every Other Week</option>
                <option value="30">Repeat Every Month</option>
              </select>

            </div>
        </div>                          
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" name="addPrimaryEvent" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
       </form>
```

I get this from var_dump($_POST):

```
  array(8) {
  ["inputEventTitle"]=>
  string(5) "Title"
  ["inputEventDescription"]=>
  string(11) "Description"
  ["inputEventStartTime"]=>
  string(6) "2:00AM"
  ["inputEventEndTime"]=>
  string(6) "3:00AM"
  ["inputEventDate"]=>
  string(10) "05-26-2014"
  ["inputEventEndDate"]=>
  string(10) "05-29-2014"
  ["inputEventFrequency"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["addPrimaryEvent"]=>
  string(6) "Submit"
}
```

Comment: Paste in the form and the js code

Comment: The code under the <script> tag won`t change automatically, you need to post the form to a script, also use $('#checkbox-02').is(':checked');

Comment: @JakeGould - yes. There are fields before and after the checkbox being posted successfully.

Comment: @KA_lin - I'm not sure I understand. The <script> code is just for visual appearance on the form. It works fine. The issue is after hitting submit, all fields but the checkbox post, even when the checkbox is selected.

Comment: And if you put a var_dump($_POST); at the beginning of the form you don`t see the 'test' key after the submit?

Comment: THat's correct. I'll add what I get to the post right now.

Comment: I'd sugguest validating your code real quick before continuing. There are several duplicate ID's, your divs aren't closed, and while browsers support it, you should not have an empty action attribute for your form. (Use `?`)

Comment: @Conexion - all DIVs are closed, I just posted the form part of the HTML to keep the post a bit shorter. I'll check the duplicate IDs, do you think that could cause the issue?

Comment: @user2521738: I tested it and after checking the box I got the key 'test'

Comment: @Conexion - there were 4 duplicate IDs - all were posting though. Fixed though, thanks! :)

Comment: Also read this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318428/submit-form-fields-inside-displaynone-element) else you won`t be able to post fields having 'display:none'

Comment: At the very bottom of your form, before your form closing tag, your `div.modal-footer` isn't closed. It's important to make sure that your HTML is valid before going on to seeing what the issue might be, as lots of small things can cause different unexpected problems. :)

Comment: @KA_lin I tried again to be sure, and I am not getting the key. The fields in the display:none is posting fine - maybe that applies when the input is set to display:none, not the surrounding div?

Comment: @Conexion - I didn't post the line after that, but it is closed. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that there are no more events binded to the checkbox? I have stripped the jQuery code and everything works fine

Comment: @Jacob If you're closing the tag outside the form, you have malformed HTML. You can't do `<form><div></form></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Very unclear why this would not work. But I noticed inconsistencies & imbalance in the HTML tags as well as an empty `action=""` which is not HTML5 valid. For more details, see t[his great answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a#1132015).

So I have set it to `#`. You might want to actually change that to the full filename or path to the PHP script such as `action="form.php"`. Or you could leave it out altogether like this:

```
<form class="cmxform form-horizontal tasi-form" id="commentForm" role="form" action="#" method="post">
```

But I prefer to be explicit & recommend the `action="form.php"` way of handling things. Here is your cleaned up HTML form:

```
<form class="cmxform form-horizontal tasi-form" id="commentForm" role="form" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEventTitle" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Event Title</label>

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEventTitle" name="inputEventTitle" placeholder="Event Title" required="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEventDescription" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Description</label>

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEventTitle" name="inputEventDescription" placeholder="Event Description" required="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEventStartTime" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Start Time</label>

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select name="inputEventStartTime" class="form-control" id="dp1" required="">
                <option value="12:00AM">
                    12:00AM
                </option>

                <option value="12:15AM">
                    12:15AM
                </option>

                <option value="12:30AM">
                    12:30AM
                </option>

                <option value="12:45AM">
                    12:45AM
                </option>

                <option value="1:00AM">
                    1:00AM
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEventEndTime" class="col-lg-2 control-label">End Time</label>

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select name="inputEventEndTime" class="form-control" id="dp1" required="">
                <option value="1:00AM">
                    1:00AM
                </option>

                <option value="1:15AM">
                    1:15AM
                </option>

                <option value="1:30AM">
                    1:30AM
                </option>

                <option value="1:45AM">
                    1:45AM
                </option>

                <option value="2:00AM">
                    2:00AM
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Date</label>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="dp1" name="inputEventDate" type="text" size="16" class="form-control" required="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEventDate" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Repeat?</label>

        <div class="col-lg-10 checkboxes">
            <input name="test" id="checkbox-02" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Yes, I want to repeat this event.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="repeatUntilDIV" style="display:none;">
        <label for="inputEventEndDate" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Repeat Until</label>

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input name="inputEventEndDate" id="eventEndDate" type="text" placeholder="End Date" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="repeatFrequencyDIV" style="display:none;">
        <label for="inputEventFrequency" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Repeat Every</label>

        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select name="inputEventFrequency" class="form-control" id="dp1">
                <option value="1">
                    Repeat Every Day
                </option>

                <option value="2">
                    Repeat Every Other Day
                </option>

                <option value="7">
                    Repeat Every Week
                </option>

                <option value="14">
                    Repeat Every Other Week
                </option>

                <option value="30">
                    Repeat Every Month
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button> <input type="submit" name="addPrimaryEvent" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```