# Populating the form with default values on click of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with 3 radio buttons and 3 text boxes , on click of a radio button one input field shows up and other two hides (using jQuery). 
Now I wish to submit the form by filling the two hidden fields with some default values , 
I have tried to assign values to this two hidden fields but it didn't worked ,

Please help me , here's what i have tried till know and an  unable to assign values to the hidden text field .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".blue").show();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.red{ background: #ff0000; }
.green{ background: #00ff00; }
.blue{ background: #0000ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red"> red</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="blue"> blue</label>
</div>
<form id="myform">
    <div class="red box">
        <input type="text" >            
    </div>
    <div class="green box"><input type="text" ></div>
    <div class="blue box"><input type="text" ></div>           
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: u didn't set name to that three input textfield and you are not assign value to these.

Comment: Try the Keith Wood jQuery plugin - http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know when a form element is set to `display: none`, you can't capture its value when you submit the form. You should hide them in a different way just don't use `display: none`.

[Submit form fields inside display:none element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318428/submit-form-fields-inside-displaynone-element)

Comment: That's not true. Elements with `display: none;` are indeed sent to the server, only `disabled` elements are not: https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/73ezqj33/1/

Comment: You're right. It seems that problem is no longer true today. Besides, the last time I encountered this issue was years ago same with the guy who answered in the link I provided. Thanks for clearing that.

Answer (score 0):

First your `<input type="text" />` don't have a name, you need to assign them names so form will pass their values"

```
<input type="text" name="redText" />
```

You can just use `.val()` instead of `.attr("value")`.
To assign values to hidden input texts you can just use:

```
if ($(this).val() == "red") {
    $(".box").hide();
    $(".red").show();
    $(".box input[type=text]").val("It Works!");
    $(".red input[type=text]").val("ahhaaa!");
}
//and so on
```

And you may consider using `hidden inputs`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="greenHidden" value="the_value_to_be_sent" />
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/tzxs91b8/1/)