# $_POST of ajax appended inputs field always returns empty value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Iam using ajax method for fetching data from a page users.php and the results from this page are set as html inside a div in parent page list-users.php

The **users.php** returns the html like below

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>John<input name="user_id[]" type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sam<input name="user_id[]" type="hidden" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

These values are put inside a div using `$("#userlists").html();` in **list-users.php**

```
<form method="post">
<div id="userlists">
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>John<input name="user_id[]" type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sam<input name="user_id[]" type="hidden" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit_users" value="Save" />
</form>
```

When I submit the form, the `user_id[]` always returns empty. I don't know what the error is. Is it possible to get the values of `user_id[]` while submitting form?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_users']))
{
 print_r($_POST['user_id']);
//this returns empty data always
}
?>

var value='{"slno":"'+number+'","empcode":"'+code+'"}';
    jQuery.ajax({       
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'inc/users.php',
        data: 'values='+value,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            if(html)
            {               
                $("#userlists").html(html);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#userlists").html("Error Occured.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Share the php code aswell. And the ajax-code.

Comment: How do you handling the submit? Via ajax or you are reading $_POST array?

Comment: share full code ie :  Ajax  and Php code

Comment: How do you submit form without a Submit button?

Comment: There is a submit button submit_users inside form@php-dev

Comment: @Anoop i tried your code and get this result "Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )" at print_r

Comment: @Anoop What you are getting in html ? after ajax ?

Comment: Ajax is working fine for me. The problem is when i try to submit the form, the values inside the text box returns empty

Comment: But it didn't work work me..@DestinatioN

Comment: I wonder how the button is still there after doing `$("#userlists").html(html);` !!

Comment: Sorry its ouside the userlists div. @php-dev

Comment: @Anoop could you pls post the whole structure of your file

Comment: @Where is your javascript code located?

Comment: In the bottom of the page afte </body>

Comment: Very strange. Did $_POST['submit_users'] was send ?

Comment: May be this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318428/submit-form-fields-inside-displaynone-element

Comment: Try changing data: `'values='+value` to data: `{'values':value}` It is an AJAX-post and you should catch $_POST['values'] in inc/users.php

Comment: Yes.$_POST['submit_users'] is working and the text boxes in the parent page returns values. Poblem Only with the ajax appended html

Comment: @isnisn this wouldn't help because the varaible "$_POST['user_id']" is empty

Comment: @Anoop so print_r returns "Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )" or "Array ( [0] => [1] => )"

Comment: Have you tried changning `<input name="user_id[]"`to `<input name="user_id_1"` and so on? I believe its empty because its not an "input-group" your are posting. I know this works: `<select name="user_id[]"><option value="1"></option></select>"` then $_POST['user_id'][0] would be 1

Comment: Input must be in array because there may be different number of inputs each time@isnish

Comment: Your table of user-list is visible? If not, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318428/submit-form-fields-inside-displaynone-element

Comment: this code working fine for me results : Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )

You submit form with ajax or normal form submit ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this ajax request.

```
var value='{"slno":"'+number+'","empcode":"'+code+'"}';
    jQuery.ajax({       
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'inc/users.php',
        cache: false,
        data: { "values" : value },
        dataType: "html"
        success: function(html){
            if(html)
            {               
                $("#userlists").html(html);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#userlists").html("Error Occured.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Your ajax response is html, so you need to add `dataType: "html"`

Also put all html in one line like this.

```
<table width="100%" border="0"><tr><td>John<input name="user_id[]" type="hidden" value="1" /></td></tr><tr><td>Sam<input name="user_id[]" type="hidden" value="2" /></td></tr></table>
```

And mention Action in form tag too. May be this would be the problem.

Comment: The ajax request is not his problem. '$_POST['user_id']' is empty before the ajax request starts

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not treating user_id[] as multidimensional arrays. When you read the post you are missing out on the key. It works when i try this:

```
$user_ids = $_POST['user_id'];

foreach( $user_ids as $key => $n ) {
  echo "The user_id is ".$n.".PHP_EOL;
}
```