# How to mimic the aspnet mvc code for LabelFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My "unenhanced" code looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "home"))
{
    <!-- old group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Query.artist)        
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Query.artist, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Query.artist)
    </div>
    ...
}
```

But I want to enhance it and add a toggle feature for each `form-group`, like this:

```
<script>
    var toggleProperty = function(targetCheckbox) {
        var id = targetCheckbox.id.split('-')[0];
        var inputDiv = document.getElementById(id + "-inputdiv");
        inputDiv.style.display = (inputDiv.style.display !== "none") ? "none" : "";
    }
</script>

<!-- new group -->
<input type="checkbox" id="property1-toggler" value="false" onchange="return toggleProperty(this)"/> <label for="property1">name for property1</label>
<div id="property1-inputdiv">
    <input class="form-control" id="property1" name="property1" type="text" value="property1 default value">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="property1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I would like to know where [in the aspnet mvc source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) I can find the code for `LabelFor` etc.

This way I could better understand how it works, and create an extension function like:

```
public static IHtmlContent FullGroupFor<TModel, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression);
```

Comment: Would it be easier to just create a new extension that calls `LabelFor`? Start with that result, then add your stuff afterwards inside a new extension method?

Comment: @krillgar Thanks for the hint, after some work I've published [a solution to the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43402960/831138).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with @krillgar's suggestion, and it worked:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Given an input property, creates a full block of:
    /// 1. checkbox (to allow toggle)
    /// 2. label
    /// 3. extra content if needed (shown above the textbox)
    /// 4. textbox
    /// 5. validation message
    /// 
    /// 3+4+5 are shown only if the checkbox is clicked (toggle functionality)
    /// </summary>
    public static IHtmlContent FullGroupFor<TModel, TResult>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
        string placeholder = null,
        IHtmlContent extraContent = null)
    {            
        var propertyId = string.Join("_", expression.Body.ToString().Split('.').Skip(1));

        var method = expression.Compile();
        var value = method(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
        var hasValue = (value != null);

        var builder = new HtmlContentBuilder();

        builder.AppendHtml("<div class=\"form-group\">");
        builder.AppendHtml($"<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{propertyId}-toggler\" {(hasValue ? "checked" : "")} onchange=\"return toggleProperty(this)\"/>");
        builder.AppendHtml("&nbsp");
        builder.AppendHtml(htmlHelper.LabelFor<TResult>(expression, null, null));
        builder.AppendHtml($"<div id=\"{propertyId}-inputdiv\" style=\"display:{(hasValue ? "" : "none")}\">");
        if (extraContent != null)
            builder.AppendHtml(extraContent);
        builder.AppendHtml(htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = placeholder }));
        builder.AppendHtml(htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression));
        builder.AppendHtml("</div>");
        builder.AppendHtml("</div>");

        return builder;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Javascript code necessary to run the toggle code in the previous function.
    /// </summary>
    public static IHtmlContent GetToggleScript(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        => new HtmlString(@"
            <script>
                var toggleProperty = function(targetCheckbox) {
                    var id = targetCheckbox.id.split('-')[0];
                    var inputDiv = document.getElementById(id + '-inputdiv');
                    inputDiv.style.display = (inputDiv.style.display !== 'none') ? 'none' : '';
                }
            </script>
        ");
}
```

It is also important what @Soviut's added, which is: "it's not a good idea to toggle groups or fieldsets with display: none because hidden form elements will not be submitted". In my case it's OK because it matches my specifications (a field will be sent as `null` if it's not been checked by the user).

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8318442/1195056), modern browsers **do** submit `display:none` elements. However, they still will not submit ones that are disabled.

Answer (score 2):

All `LabelFor` is doing is creating a `<label>` with a `for` attribute. This attribute points at an id of a form element such as a textbox or checkbox, and will give it focus (or toggle the checkbox).

```
<label for="my-textbox">
<input id="my-textbox" type="text">
```

Form groups don't have labels. Those are most likely being created using [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) which has as `<legend>` tag for displaying an explanation of each set.

Also, it's not a good idea to toggle groups or fieldsets with `display: none` because hidden form elements will not be submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't aware that `display: none` would have the effect of not submitting hidden form elements. After some work I've published [a solution to the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43402960/831138). I am curious about an alternative to `display: none` for toggling the content.