# TextArea not sending data on Submit

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Ajax to post my data, while using inspect elemet, I can see the post data from all other fields, but text area field comes empty, so the data fails to be saved to the database.

```
 function addblog() {

        save_method = 'add';

        url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/blog/post_new_blog')?>";

        $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: "POST",
             data: $('#addblog').serialize(),
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                  alert('Saved');
             },
             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error adding / update data');
       }
   });
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="editor-one" class="editor-wrapper"></div>
    <textarea  id="descr" class="text" name="desc" style="display:none;"></textarea>
```

PHP:

```
    public function post_new_blog()
{
    $data = array(
        'blog_title' => $this->input->post('title', true),
        'blog_content' => $this->input->post('desc', true),
        'blog_tags' => $this->input->post('tags', true),
    );

    $insert = $this->main_model->save_new_posts($data);

    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
 }
```

Comment: Please do not have space between opening/closing textarea

Comment: change style to `style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;"`. It should work. for similar question look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318428/submit-form-fields-inside-displaynone-element)

Comment: fields with `display:none` are not send

Comment: @jagad89 On it, lemme take a look

Comment: @jagad89 DOne it, still no difference

Comment: @manian Yeah, its not supposed to have that, lemme edit. I think the site did the spacing, lemme correct

Comment: What's your purpose ? Why you wanted to textarea not visible on page ?

Comment: @jagad89 Form data, other fields post their data, but data from textarea comes empty

Comment: Yes.. because its hidden and empty..for just time being remove all style.. type something  in textarea and then submit.. you will get data `<textarea  id="desc" class="text" name="desc" ></textarea>`

Comment: @jagad89 now its working after doing that

Comment: What you trying to achieve ?, i can't understand.

Comment: @RST : it seems not to be an issue anymore in modern browser (>2016). Fields are submitted even if display is set to `none`. Only `disabled` won't be.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data as follows:

```
data: $('#addblog').serialize(),
```

does your

```
<textarea  id="descr" class="text" name="desc" style="display:none;"></textarea>
```

inside html element with id **addblog**?

Meanwhile, i didn't understand why you set display to none for textarea?