# HTML hidden fields when shown doesn't post value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hello I've got a question,
i have 3 hidden fields in a `<form>` .
There is shown only one of them when i select a radio button.
When i submit the form i didn't get the value and cant write it in the database, what am i doing wrong ?

the `type_chooser_result_box` is hidden and shows only one of the necassary divs (`add_dvd`, `add_book` or `add_furniture`)

my form in the HTML :

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="addProduct">
    <label for="NAME">SKU is added automaticaly: </label><br>
    <input type="text" id="add_name" name="add_name" disabled><br>

    <label for="NAME">add Name: </label><br>
    <input type="text" id="add_name" name="add_name" required><br>

    <label for="number">add Price: </label><br>
    <input type="text" id="add_price" name="add_price" required><br>

    <label for="type_chooser">Choose product type: </label>
    <div id="type_chooser" onclick="hide_box()">
        <label for="dvd">DVD</label>
        <input type="radio" id="dvd" name="add_type" value="dvd">
        <br>
        <label for="book">Book</label>
        <input type="radio" id="book" name="add_type" value="book">
        <br>
        <label for="furniture">Furniture</label>
        <input type="radio" id="furniture" name="add_type" value="furniture">
        <br>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div class="type_chooser_result_box" id="add_value">
        <div id="add_dvd">
            <label for="add_value">DVD Size in MB</label>
            <input type="text" id="add_value" name="add_value"><br>
        </div>
        <div id="add_book">
            <label for="add_value">Book weight in g</label>
            <input type="text" id="add_value" name="add_value"><br>
        </div>

        <div id="add_furniture">
            <label for="add_value">Height</label>
            <input type="text" id="add_value" name="add_value"><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

and here is my javascript for hiding the type_chooser_result_box div and show it with an slide effect:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".type_chooser_result_box").hide();
    });

    $("#dvd").click(function() {
        if ($("#dvd").is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#add_dvd").show("slide");
            $(".type_chooser_result_box").show("slide");
            $("#add_furniture").hide("slide");
            $("#add_book").hide("slide");
        }
    });

    $("#book").click(function() {
        if ($("#book").is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#add_book").show("slide");
            $(".type_chooser_result_box").show("slide");
            $("#add_dvd").hide("slide");
            $("#add_furniture").hide("slide");
        }
    });

    $("#furniture").click(function() {
        if ($("#furniture").is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#add_furniture").show("slide");
            $(".type_chooser_result_box").show("slide");
            $("#add_dvd").hide("slide");
            $("#add_book").hide("slide");
        }
    });

</script>
```

the result of my submit when i vardump() the $_POST is

```
array(4) { ["add_name"]=> string(4) "Harry Potter" ["add_price"]=> string(2) "9.99" ["add_type"]=> string(4) "book" ["add_value"]=> string(0) "" }
```

im not disabling the divs as far i know so it isn't the result from this : [Submit form fields inside display:none element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318428/submit-form-fields-inside-displaynone-element)

Comment: You have non-unique names and ID's. So when submitting form last field value overwrites every other fields with same name. Also your `for="add_value"` will always trigger input of `DVD Size in MB`. Consider using unique ID's and names

Comment: thanks this helps me a lot, i solved it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `type_chooser_result_box` Div **your textboxes having same ID**.
Every element must have unique ID (but can have name attribute same). 
So when ever you are submitting the first ID element value will be posted.

1. Remove `add_value` from Div
2. Assign unique ID to your textboxes.