# POST value of checkbox sent with basic HTML form always returns 'on'

Tags: php, html, forms, post, checkbox

I need to implement a very basic honeypot hidden checkbox server side validation. This is my HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="handle-form.php">
    <input type="checkbox" id="validate_box" name="validate_box" style="display:none !important" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

When I try to print out the `$_POST['validate_box']` in my `handle-form.php`, it always returns *'on'*. Same goes for `isset($_POST['validate_box'])`, always returns *true*. It doesn't matter if the checkbox is checked or not.

I've also tried adding a custom default value to the checkbox and compare it in PHP, but same result.

What is the issue here?

Comment: How do you submit the form?

Comment: The checkbox doesn't have a value so there's no way it displays `on`.  Unless you ave other code or JS or something.

Comment: @AbraCadaver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox: _“If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is `on`”_

Comment: @CBroe Noted.  I don't think I ever didn't specify a value myself.

Answer (score -2):

This should be a pretty simple fix:

Set the input field to `visibility:hidden` and/or `position:absolute` instead. Fields will not be sent to the server with `display:none`, but will be with `visibility:hidden`. By also toggling "position" to "absolute" you should get the same visual effect.

Answer borrowed from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318442/15594929

Hope I could help. Have a great day/night (:

Comment: Also, putting `style="visibility: hidden"` right in the form element kind of screams "I am a honeypot field". Put that in the stylesheet.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work at all. I've tried inline styling as well as external stylesheet, but the `$_POST['validate_box']` is **always** "on".