# jquery copying values with val() seems to remove linebreaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering why javascript/jquery removes my linebreaks (\n) when I copy a textarea's value (id="t") to another element (id="t_hidden").

```
$('#t_hidden').val($('#t').val());
```

When I do sth. with value of $('#t_hidden') I recognize that my linebreaks have disappeared. 
Does anybody know why?

Comment: what element types are we talking here?

Comment: you could probably to .html()  instead of .val()  depending on what type of elements your talking about

Comment: Related: [Post newline/carriage return as hidden field value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667915/post-newline-carriage-return-as-hidden-field-value)

Comment: @epascarello O thanks! I think your question has solved my problem. It was copied to an input element. This will maybe automatically remove the linebreaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the destination element a textarea? If not, the linebreaks could be copied, but ignored as whitespace. You'd need to replace them with a `<br />` to have them work.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Elements with the type of hidden and textboxes so not have line breaks, they will be removed when you set the value. If you want to maintain the linebreaks, use a textarea and set the display to none.

Comment: An `<input type="hidden">` element seems to keep line feeds as well (at least in Firefox).