# How to add new line in HiddenField value in HTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have HiddenField in HTMl :

```
<asp:HiddenField  ID="BodyHiddenField"  runat="server"  Value = " "  />
```

Now I want to add multiple line in **Value** of this text :

**Thank you for registration .Your registration has been confirmed. Date : 24 Feb 2019   Time : 09:30 AM**

To be :

```
First Line = Thank you for registration .Your registration has been confirmed. 

Second Line =  Date : 24 Feb 2019 

Third Line = Time : 09:30
```

Comment: `Value` is just a string you can format your multiple string with using seperator.

Comment: You can use \n for line breaks, what is the context of what you're doing with the value?

Comment: Can not use \n  there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post newline/carriage return as hidden field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667915/post-newline-carriage-return-as-hidden-field-value)

Comment: is not duplicate , my question has asp:HiddenField

Comment: It is a duplicate until you tell people how it is different. We need to know what you're trying to do with it before anyone can suggest anything. Help us help you.

Comment: asp:HiddenField -> not allow character \n . but <input type="hidden" -> allow character \n

Comment: `asp:HiddenField` is rendered to `<input type="hidden" />` . How are you setting the value? In line in the .aspx or code behind in .cs?

Comment: Why not taking a `label` and set the `visible`. Then you can use the `\n`

Answer (score 0):

In the PageLoad event, assign value to hidden field

```
 BodyHiddenField.Value="Thank you for registration .Your registration has been confirmed.\n\n Date : 24 Feb 2019 \n\n Time : 09:30"
```